# How can I merge these two lines of code into one (Python 3.X)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, join, replace

```
text = ''.join(sorted([x for x in input()]))
text = text.replace('+', '', text.count('+'))
```

I just it love it when you can do all sort of things in one line with Python.

Comment: you can use method chaining `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
text = ''.join(sorted(input())).replace('+', '')
```

OR

```
text = ''.join(sorted(input().replace('+', '')))
```

- You don't need to use list comprehension. Just pass the `input()` to sorted(); `sorted` support any iterable.
- the 3rd argument to `str.replace()` is redundant. Because the code is replacing all occurences of `+`.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, this is not exactly the same code, but in this case result is similar:

```
text = ''.join(sorted([x for x in input() if x != '+']))
```

Instead of creating whole string and then replacing one character, you can simply remove it in first list comperhesion.